# Triplicated records on insert with select

Tags: mysql, group-by, insert-select

The following code aways creates triplicated records, but if I remove the transaction commands, it works as expected, inserting only 1 record for each number on the `in` clause:

```
insert into table1(id2, col) 
select col2, 1 
from table2
where col2 in (1, 2, 3) and col2 not in (select id2 from table1 where col = 1)
group by col2;
```

Is this a MySQL bug? The same statement don't cause duplicated records on MSSQL Server.
Is it possible to run this queries or similar ones with transaction on without duplicating records?

**Example data before queries:**

```
table1
id | id2 | col
==============
 -- empty --

table2
id | col2
==============
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 2
7  | 3
8  | 3
9  | 3
```

**Example data after queries:**

```
table1 (* duplicated records I don't want)
id | id2 | col
==============
1  | 1   | 1
2  | 1   | 1  *
3  | 1   | 1  *
4  | 2   | 1
5  | 2   | 1  *
6  | 2   | 1  *
7  | 3   | 1
8  | 3   | 1  *
9  | 3   | 1  *

table2 keeps the same
```

**Obs.:**

- `table2` has duplicated values.
- Running the select query alone returns only the desired results (no duplicates).
- It seems that `insert into() select` ignores `distinct` and `group by` clauses.

**Edit:**

I found that this problem occurs because MySQL ignores the `GROUP BY` clause on an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query.
Is there a way to group this records on insert?

Comment: Must be your code, not the statements. Can't reproduce this neither with MySQL 5.5.32 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b29ad/2/0, nor with 5.6.6 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b29a/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this problem occurs because MySQL ignores the `GROUP BY` clause on an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query.

Don't know exactly why, but if I use a query that doesn't use `GROUP BY` or `DISTICT` it works.